# Error when building project with monodroid/mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've got an error when I try to build a project (monodroid/mvvmcross).
This is the message error :

```
Error   37  The type 'Android.App.ListActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'.
```

Someone have an idea how to solve this problem ? This is strange because there wasn't this error before.

This error is located in MvxDialogActivityView.cs (cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that parts of your code is compiled against Xamarin.Android while others are compiled against Mono for Android.

See: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1476/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-android-4-6-0

You will need to recompile all parts of your application to target the same version of Xamarin's products.

Comment: You're right, I make a "Clean" of my solution then rebuild and it works ! Fortunately more fear than harm :) I've got an another problem (http://tiny.cc/mzd2uw) if you could help me that would be great.